# Primitive type dependency injection in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-config

Can you please provide me with an example of primitive type dependency injection in spring boot. I have tried once but TestConfiguration which is my custom bean definition class does not detect or does not recognize by spring boot application.
here is my code,

//Engine class

```
package com.test2.projectTest;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class Engine {

private String msg;

public String getMsg() {
    return msg;
}

public void setMsg(String msg) {
    this.msg = msg;
}
}
```

//Test Configuration

```
package com.test2.projectTest;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class TestConfiguration {

@Bean("engine")
public Engine engine(){
    Engine engine = new Engine();
    engine.setMsg("Message is injected");
    return engine;
}
}
```

//spring main application

```
package com.test2.projectTest;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication; 
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;

@SpringBootApplication
public class ProjectTestApplication {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(ProjectTestApplication.class, args);
}
}
```

//JUnit Test

```
package com.test2.projectTest;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.TestConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import 
org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class ProjectTestApplicationTests {

@Test
public void contextLoads() {

    ApplicationContext apc = new 
AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(TestConfiguration.class);
    Engine e = (Engine) apc.getBean("engine");
    e.getMsg();
}
}

// Output - org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: 
No bean named 'engine' available
```

Please suggest any solution to above issue

Comment: What does this have to do with primitive types?

Comment: and why are you creating two contexts, one with spring runner, another with annotationconfigapplicationcontext? how does it work in your actual app, outside of tests?

Comment: i'm finding how to inject value into msg property in Engine class which is primitive type using spring boot. Any suggestion?.

Comment: you have a problem with creating spring configuration. your error has nothing to do with value injection. Try to fix your configuration first, so you would be able to create a bean.

Comment: Any ways can you please correct the above code for me please?

Comment: You could start with the tutorial: https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/

Comment: what does the link you provided?. It is redirecting me the same post that i posted.

Answer (score 0):

Add @componentscan annotation in main class and provide engine class package and it should work